# Как перебрать все файлы и папки в каталоге и записать их в список в древовидной структуре?

Tags: c#

Собственно, заголовок говорит о моём вопросе больше, чем я здесь написал. Так что, пожалуйста, кто знает, как это сделать?
Классы в моей программе:

Класс для папки

```
public class MyFolder
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    
    public ObservableCollection<MyFolder> Folders { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<MyFile> Files { get; set; }

    public MyFolder()
    {
        Folders = new ObservableCollection<MyFolder>();
        Files = new ObservableCollection<MyFile>();
    }
}
```

Класс для файла

```
public class MyFile
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Используйте [Directory.EnumerateFiles](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.enumeratefiles?view=netcore-3.1) c параметром RecurseSubdirectories и заполняйте вашу структуру.

Comment: Извините, но я не могу найти параметр RecurseSubdirectories

Comment: [Перегрузка с SearchOptions](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.enumeratefiles?view=netcore-3.1#System_IO_Directory_EnumerateFiles_System_String_System_String_System_IO_SearchOption_)

Comment: @A K https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.io.searchoption?view=netcore-3.1 тут только два поля: AllDirectories и TopDirectoryOnly